# GooglePlacesSDK Returning Error 500

Tags: ios, google-places-api, google-places

I am getting an error from google places:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [{
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "backendError",
            "message": "Backend Error"
        }],
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Backend Error"
    }
}
```

I am using the `Google Places API for iOS` version `2.0.0`. The error looks strange. Is there anyone who experienced that and help me getting rid of that error?

Comment: Same issue here, looks like Google side problem

Comment: Same issue here.. Had the issue yesterday. Worked again today, but started failing later on. No idea how to get rid of it yet.