# Google Places api for android network error

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm using the google places autocomplete fragment to search for places. It has been working for a few weeks now and all of a sudden today, I'm getting the following error:

```
E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=65, operation=AddPlace
                                             OperationException[Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null}]
                                                 at amsa.b(:com.google.android.gms:266)
                                                 at amro.a(:com.google.android.gms:60)
                                                 at lin.run(:com.google.android.gms:111)
                                                 at llt.run(:com.google.android.gms:450)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                 at lqc.run(:com.google.android.gms:17)
                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I've tried setting the filter to null as the posted solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845946/google-places-api-for-android-error-statusstatuscode-network-error-resolution).

My manifest has the following meta-data :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8"/>
```

I'm calling the fragment with the following code:`Intent intent =
                                new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                                        .setFilter(null)
                                        .build(MainActivity.this);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);`

I would like to point out that this code has been working for a few weeks without any problems, and I haven't made any changes to it.

Comment: I'm also having troubles with the Autocomplete API for the last 4 hours. I haven't changed any of the code

Answer (score 1):

Everything is working again over here, hope you guys can say the same. Looks like it was a problem at google

Answer (score 0):

Seeing errors as well.  Looks like Google Places API might be having an outage.

[GooglePlacesSDK Returning Error 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118058/googleplacessdk-returning-error-500)

Comment: I'm glad to see that I'm not the only one having issues. It seems tho that the problem is only occuring on mobile because my website is working without any issues. The google maps app on android is working fine so no problems there with the place search

Comment: {statusCode=PLACES_API_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, resolution=null} I am getting this error, can you explain the reason for this response?